# Python - pydriosm - Import - OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, import

I followed instructions as per https://pypi.org/project/pydriosm/1.0.10/ to install pydriosm

When it came to importing the package via jupyter notebook, after running:

```
import pydriosm as dri
```

I got the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-544834b2defe> in <module>
----> 1 import pydriosm as dri

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydriosm\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from .download_BBBike import *
      2 from .download_GeoFabrik import *
----> 3 from .dump_GeoFabrik import *
      4 from .osm_psql import *
      5 from .read_GeoFabrik import *

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydriosm\dump_GeoFabrik.py in <module>
     15 from pydriosm.download_GeoFabrik import fetch_region_subregion_tier, retrieve_names_of_subregions_of
     16 from pydriosm.download_GeoFabrik import get_default_path_to_osm_file
---> 17 from pydriosm.osm_psql import OSM
     18 from pydriosm.read_GeoFabrik import parse_osm_pbf_layer_data, read_osm_pbf
     19 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydriosm\osm_psql.py in <module>
      5 
      6 import pandas as pd
----> 7 import shapely.wkt
      8 import sqlalchemy
      9 import sqlalchemy.engine.reflection

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\wkt.py in <module>
      2 """
      3 
----> 4 from shapely import geos
      5 
      6 # Pickle-like convenience functions

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py in <module>
    143     if os.getenv('CONDA_PREFIX', ''):
    144         # conda package.
--> 145         _lgeos = CDLL(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'Library', 'bin', 'geos_c.dll'))
    146     else:
    147         try:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

The package seems to be installed correctly after running `pip install pydriosm`

I tried googling this problem, but couldn't find any thread that would match up with my problem

Comment: Can you run ``import pydriosm`` in cmd without exception?

Comment: Oh yeah, haven't thought of that check - just run it in cmd and it's working...

Comment: Perhaps your notebook and console are running in different Python environments?